# Загрузить проект на github целиком

Tags: git, github

Добрый день, коллеги.
Есть готовый проект на github, как сделать push так, чтобы загрузились все файлы и папки(даже те, что в gitignore)? Удалять файлы .gitignore не вариант, есть ли другие методы?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опция `-f` (`--force`) в `git add` игнорирует правила игнорирования. следующая команда добавит в индекс вообще все файлы из рабочего дерева:

```
git add -f .
```

после этого

```
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно!

Comment: Только в качестве добавления могу посоветовать вот этот линк: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.ru.html. Для меня было очень полезно в начале